# How to find k-way second preimages

Tags: collision-resistance, sha-256, 2nd-preimage-resistance

For example:

Assuming someone has found a second preimage for SHA-256. In other words, for SHA256(M1)=H, someone has found M2 which SHA256(M2)=H

Now, is it possible to generate k-way second preimages faster than brute force? To illustrate my point:

For SHA256(M1)=SHA256(M2)=H, is there a way to find:

SHA256(M1)=SHA256(M2)=SHA256(M3)=SHA256(M4)=...=SHA256(Mk)=H

faster than brute force?

EDIT:

I did find some relevant information here: (https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bc44/a277e6e10ff318ea7ecb06af12a191d1193a.pdf)

According to the paper, by using an extension of Joux's multicollision technique, it is possible to generate multiple second preimages faster than brute force. However, this doesn't seem to match what I want to find, because the technique described in the paper creates multi-preimages with the *same message block*, but *different initial values*. I want a technique to find multi-preimages with different message blocks.

Comment: I *wonder* if that is dependent on how the second pre-image was found. If you found it by sheer luck then I would guess the answer is no. Of course, if you'd find one by just trying then people would start scratching their heads and try to find out what had just happened.

Answer (score 1):

Given a single collision I know of no efficient algorithm to convert it to a multi collision.

However given an algorithm which finds a free start collision. As in one that would work with any initial value we can trivially create $2^k$ multi collision for the cost of running the algorithm $k$ times sequentially.

Just find a collision and then use the output of the hash(before padding/finalization) as the new IV. And run collision finding algorithm again.

If you want multi way 2nd preimage, I can't think of something fast, but cab beat bruteforce. Just looking for a preimage by bruteforce starting from a muliway collision is faster than bruteforce. You find $2^k$ multi preimage for the cost of k times collision finding ( $2^{n/2}$ for naive}) plus $2^n$ single brute force for preimage. Vs naive multicollision which would take $2^{n+k}$ to find a $2^k$ preimages for a single value.